# iOS MKMapView filter all Museums

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I was trying to display a MKMapView showing all the museums in a city. I haven't understood if this is a built in feature of the maps or I need to get the data somewhere else. Online I was seeing an example of government databases providing the information and location and then this was being added to the map. Does the map have this feature built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not built-in feature of the map (in apple map). But you have to make a filter (Query) that can fetch response what you needs (response will be in JSON format) and manipulate it in your map as a Annotaion.

Comment: Do you know any other map services that have this feature built in? It seems that not even google maps has it built in